# REST API 404 on a specific linux server

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, rest, http

I'm using Spring boot to build a webapp. In dev environment(`ubuntu 14.04`), erverthing is ok. But when I push the webapp to prduction environment(`centos 7.6`), a few API start to return `404`.

The strange thing is the other APIs in the same controller is still working. When I change the webapp to another prd server,the APIs start to work fine.By the way, I connect the APIs with POSTMAN without any proxy.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Its depends on your data as well, verify if the resource you are requesting actually exists in environment's database.

Comment: and your full logs say?

Comment: Just try to check if the same data, same port, same code, and same URL